# How to use multiple Tabbar on one page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi Have this code for Tabber, but it is working fine when I used one tabbar on a page but didn't work properly for the mutiple tabber over the page.
Remember when Tabbar is used multiple time over the page, it is creating dynamically, so every time my html will have the same structure.
For example if Unordered List is having 4 child with id 1,2,3 & 4, then the another Tabbar will have the same ID.

Please help over this.

My code is below:-

I thinks, I am unable to put the logic over the jquery.

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
<li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
<li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
</ul>    
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
 <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
             Duis aute irure dolor in
        </div>
        <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
            Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        </div>
```

The script start from here ----

```
$('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
            $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
            $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        })
```

Comment: Please try to create a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are picking element by it's id (which value must be unique within the html page) but your goal is to multiplicate this code, so it has to be changed so that you are picking elements by it's class. This code should work just fine for you:

```js
 $('.parent[id^="tabbar"] ul.tabs li').click(function() {
      let tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
      let id = $(this).closest('.parent').attr('id');
      $('#' + id +' ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
      $('#' + id +' .tab-content').removeClass('current');
      $(this).addClass('current');
      $('#' + id +' .' + tab_id).addClass('current');
    })
```

```css
 .tab-content {
      display: none;
    }

    div .current {
      display: block;
    }

    ul .current {
      display: list-item;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>FIRST TABBAR</p>
<div class="parent" id="tabbar1">
   <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="tab-content tab-1 current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      <div class="tab-content tab-2">Duis aute irure dolor in</div>
      <div class="tab-content tab-3">Ut enim ad minim veniam,</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>SECOND TABBAR</p>
   <div class="parent" id="tabbar2">
   <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
      <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="tab-content tab-1 current">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
      <div class="tab-content tab-2">Duis aute irure dolor in</div>
      <div class="tab-content tab-3">Ut enim ad minim veniam,</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @ d-rybchenko ,it is working fine for one tabbar, when I used 2 times the same HTML, it is not working fine.

Comment: @ d-rybchenko Thanks a lot. Its working fine. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Added some info to my answer so that you can understand why it didnt work.

Comment: your updated code is working fine, but on the previous code only first tabbar functionality is working where as on second one it is not working.

Thanks and Regards